# search first "x" amount of characters in a line, and output entire line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a text file that could contain up to 1000 lines of data in the following format:

```
14410:3012669|EU14410|20/01/2017||||1|6|4|OUT FROM UNDER||22/02/2017 04:01:47|22/02/2017 21:19:52
14:3012670|EU016271751|20/01/2017||||2|6|4|BLOCK BET|\\acis-prod\Pictures\Entry\EU01627.jpg|22/02/2017 04:02:02|22/02/2017 21:19:52
301111:3012671|EU016275|20/01/2017||||2|6|4|VITAE MEDICAL CLINIC|\\tm-prod\Pictures\Entry\EU01.jpg|22/02/2017 04:02:11|22/02/2017 21:19:53
```

each line will start with the following format

```
"set of characters up to max of 8":"set of characters unlimited max"
```

I want to search the characters ONLY up until the first colon. Those characters could contain any amount up to a maximum of 8. (hopefully shown well in my examples above) I'm trying to search those first characters, up to the ":" of each line to see if it contains a string, and return the whole line. still new to powershell so I've only tried a simple select:

```
$path = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\acsep22\acsnic-20170222_233324.done"
Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Select-String -pattern ("14410","3011981","3011982",) | out-file $logfile |format-list
```

which works - but I didn't take into account that the string could also appear twice in the same line ( though unrelated to the first 7 characters)

for example:

```
14410:3012669|EU14410|
```

contains 14410 twice, they're unrelated in terms of their significance and I only want to search and return based on the first number

could somebody help me achieve this or could some one point me toward the cmdlet that would help?

I've tried various searches online (and via the Microsoft online resource) but a lot of results are more to do with "return the first X amount of characters" rather than "search using only the first X amount and return line"

Kind Regards

Comment: @wOxxOm - Querent does not specify that the pattern will always start at the beginning of the string; only that it will occur within the first 7 characters.

Comment: I think the querent needs to provide a better example of what he is searching for and what he expects to see as the result.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you i'll give that a go now :)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've edited my post. hoping it's a little clearer now

Comment: @Nighthawkz - So in every case, you are going to want to match the string up to the first colon, and will be searching for the _entire_ string before the first colon? More succinctly: Do you want a search for "30" to match lines that begin with "130:", "1300:", and "307:"?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin thanks for the reply. I only want the lines that match (up to the first colon) the exact string. So if my **-pattern ("14410","30")**. I only want the line that starts with exactly **14410** or exactly **30**.  I can see how my post wasn't as clear as it could be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `Where-Object` filter to check whether the string before the `:` is one of the strings you expect:

```
$strings = '14410','3011981','3011982'
Get-Content $path |Where-Object {$strings -contains ($_ -split ':')[0]}
```

This is probably the most PowerShell-idiomatic approach.

---

If you want to use `Select-String`, you'll have to construct a regex pattern that will match on strings that start with one of the strings and then a colon:

```
$strings = '14410','3011981','3011982'
$pattern = '^(?:{0}):' -f ($strings -join '|') # pattern is now '^(?:14410|3011981|3011982):' 
Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $pattern
```

If you just want the bare string itself from the output, grab the `Line` property from the objects returned by `Select-String`:

```
Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $pattern |Select-Object -Expand Line
```

or

```
Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $pattern |ForEach-Object Line
```

The pattern above uses a non-capturing group `(?:pattern-goes-here)` to match any one of the strings, at the start `^` of a string, followed by `:`.

Both solutions will work with an arbitrary number of strings

Comment: The `Where-Object` solution appears to match the querent's intent; the use of `-split` and the array subscript is a very nice and elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  thank you for this! I'm ran into a problem. it's not pulling anything back even if I try searching a line I know exists. tried both ways.ran it in ISE window to see and it looks like it's running through every line which looks like this: _C:\Users\LCIAV\Desktop\acsepto22\acsmrk-20170222_230159.done:4744:1645614|EU005936547|_  (i didn't know it would include the path In search criteria) my question changes completely appears I'm not looking for something at the start, but mid way and between **:** and **|**. thank you for your response, it does answer my (incorrect!) question

Comment: If you're using the second approach, `Select-String` will return a `MatchInfo` object - if you just want the string itself, grab the `Line` property (will update answer)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorted out the path displaying its now pulling everything back. tried to play around with the `'^(?:{0}):'` like removing ^ as its now apparent its not at the start. no dice. Is it still technically search though the path name? because the ID I want actually sits here in bold "done:307:**273499**|UK00002133376|",  rather than at the start. I also created a file with two lines like `1|123`,  `2|123` using the second answer and it still pulls back both lines. think this comment counts as a separate question so i'll raise a new question and make sure it's as accurate as possible

Comment: @Nighthawkz Yes, that sounds like a separate question - please make sure you post the input sample exactly as it is in the new q